# ListView memory leak: not able to recycle list elements (ImageView + Bitmap)

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-listview, listadapter

I have a ListView that uses an adapter to populate a list of ImageViews.  I'm following the standard practice of:

a) inflating a new view only if convertView is null, and

b) using a viewHolder to avoid calling findViewById() if convertView is not null

I'm also using an AsyncTask to populate the ImageViews from a database (or from disk cache or LRU memory cache, if possible).

Everything works fine for awhile (i.e., images populate in the list with smooth scrolling), but I have a leak that gives an OOM error after about 70 x 1.4M images have been loaded.

My understanding is that ListViews are recycled when getView() returns a non-null convertView, so I shouldn't see a memory build up like this.  In my case, the app's memory use grows every time an ImageView gets assigned a Bitmap.  And in fact, the Activity holds onto this memory even after I've cleared the underlying list via list.clear(), and zeroed out the adapter via adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated() - both in the onStop() function.

The MAT tool shows stranded Bitmaps and stranded ImageViews (approximately 1-to-1 with the images loaded), but I don't know what's holding a reference that would prevent garbage collection of the old views.

I'd appreciate any suggestions for how to track down this leak.  Thanks!

Comment: Try using either of the [LazyList by Fedor](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) or the [Universal Image Loader by nostra](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader). They simplify sorting out these issues.

Comment: Thanks, I'm already using the [ImageDownloader by Gilles Debunne](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html), with lazy loading and a few extensions (e.g., LruCache as now recommended by Google).

Comment: can you show the code?

Comment: Too much code to post.  But I determined I didn't actually have a leak, per this [follow up question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445224/calling-finish-does-not-clear-memory-references-to-activity).  Thanks anyway!