# How to prevent multiple instances of an Activity, with back button?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an example app with one `Activity`.  I'd like the user to be able to leave the app using the back button, and renter later via the app's icon without creating a new instance of the `Activity`.

The problem is, if I press the back button and renter n times, then I end up with n instances of the app (as observed in the Memory Analysis Tool).

I've tried overriding `onBackPressed()` to call `finish()`.  In this case, I can see that `onDestroy()` is called, but it still leaves multiple instances of the `Activity` in memory.  I've also tried the the different `android:launchMode`'s, including `"singleTop"`, `"singleTask"`, and `"singleInstance"`, but in all cases there are still multiple instances of the `Activity`'s class.

How do I prevent multiple instances of an `Activity` from running in this simple case?

Comment: By default it should work they way you want unless Android needs to reclaim the resources your app is using. You should read up on the Application Lifecycle.

Comment: Ah, your answer jogged my memory that one of my test devices has an unusual memory management scheme.  Specifically, Samsung S3 seems to have some kind of deferred gc, and as a result, MAT shows memory references even after other devices have more aggressively released memory (see an earlier question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445224/calling-finish-does-not-clear-memory-references-to-activity)).  I retested with Galaxy Nexus, and it behaves as expected - so I think this was a false alarm!  Thanks for the reply, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

When you click back button your activity is destroyed. It is natural that the activity is recreated everytime it takes focus. This is how it works.

Also activity is destroyed and recreated when screen orientation changes.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html. Go through the activity lifecycle.

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html.The documentation gives you an idea of how activity is pushed and popped from the back stack when user click back button and home button.

Suppose you start a new activity, it is pushed on to the back stack and it takes focus.

When the current activity starts another, the new activity is pushed on the top of the stack and takes focus. The previous activity remains in the stack, but is stopped.

When you click back button, the current activity is popped form the stack and is destroyed.
So the previous activity in the back stack takes focus.

Note: Multiple tasks can be held in the background at once. However, if the user is running many background tasks at the same time, the system might begin destroying background activities in order to recover memory, causing the activity states to be lost. See the following section about Activity state.

Comment: My question was why would MAT show an Activity active in memory, even after onDestroy() was called?  However, as I explained in my comment above, it looks like this was a false alarm, specific to a particular device.  Thanks anyway.